# How to add two binary numbers in the array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, iostream

I think I made a mistake somewhere but I can't seem to find it. I think the problem lies in adding or entering data in the wrong order. I apologize for any mistakes, English is not my primary language. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Blwu.png)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int d, n, m, carry;
  int a[10000];
  int b[10000];
  int addition[10001];
  cin>>d;
  for(int i=0; i<d; i++)
  {
    int a[10000]={0};
    int b[10000]={0};
    int addition[10001]={0};

    cin>>n;
    for(int i=n; i>=1; i--)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    cin>>m;
    for (int i=m; i>=1; i--)
    {
        cin>>b[i];
    }
    if(n<m)
    {
        n=m;
    }
    carry=0;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
      addition[i]=(a[i]+b[i]+carry)%2;  //way my teacher 
      carry=(a[i]+b[i]+carry)/2;
    }
    addition[n+1]=carry;
    // if(addition[n+1]==0)n--;
    for(int i=n; i>=0; i--)
    {
      cout<<addition[i];
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, fix wrong language name in the title and spelling in the question text.

Comment: *it does not work well*.. What is the exact issue? Error? Incorrect output??

Comment: Incorrect output

Comment: `int a[10000]={0};` does not initialize the previously declared array.

Comment: @manni66 he's also never using the previously declared arrays.

Comment: Just by looking at the code, I can spot at least two likely logic errors (in addition to the stylistic ones), but I wouldn't know if they are the problem you're talking about, so please explain what you mean by incorrect output.

Comment: @ove Incorect output,  When I wont to add 1001 and 11 but score is 1000

Answer (score 0):

I think there are at least two errors.

1) In

```
for(int i=n; i>=0; i--)
```

you're counting down to 0. But in every other loop, you've counted down to 1. Since you're counting down too far, your output would have an extra zero at the end. (For example, it would show `1000` when it should have shown `100`.)

2) Also in that loop, you're starting at `n`. But you've potentially put a carry into `n+1`, aren't you forgetting to output it too?